# Dual Boot Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04 Bootloader

Tags: dual-boot

I feel like this has been asked, but I'm still confused. I have windows 7 installed on a SSD. I want to dual boot linux with it so I partitioned 60gigs of space for the root, home, and swap. I booted from a flash drive that I have linux loaded on and began the install. My system is set to UEFI so I set it to install the bootloader on the efi partition.

The install went fine, however when I restarted, it just loads windows 7 and never gives me an option to boot into my linux install. I'm assuming that Grub2 should be the default, but I'm guessing that windows boot manager is still the default.

Can someone give me some clarification on what I need to do in order to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the EFI which boot image to use. The EFI remembers the last used boot image. Now, how exactly to do this depends on the EFI implementation. For example, on my Lenovo laptop I would enter the EFI setup by hitting a special button on the side of the computer. Then, I would go to the Boot tab and there is a list of bootloaders. You should see Ubuntu and a Windows Boot Manager of some kind. Use the designated keys to re-arrange the boot order.

Alternatively, you should be able to set it from the LiveCD/USB by running [efibootmgr](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/efibootmgr) [image: Install efibootmgr]. Note that the process below will only work if the CD/USB was booted in EFI mode, not compatibility/legacy/BIOS mode.

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

Gives you a list of your current boot order. In order to change this, you have to type a long command that is highly dependant on your system. For example, my system boot order looks like this (note the BootOrder line):

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0007,0002,0003,0000,0008,0009,000A,0005,2001
Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0003* Ubuntu
Boot0005* Network Boot: Atheros Boot Agent
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0008* Internal HDD: SAMSUNG MZMPA016HMCD-000L1      
Boot0009* SATA HDD    : ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB          
Boot000A* SATA ODD    : HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GU70N           
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
```

It does 'ubuntu' first, followed by 'Windows Boot Manager', then 'Windows Boot Manager' (again?), then 'Ubuntu' (yet again? -- guess I gotta get that sorted out), then 'Lenovo Recovery System', etc.

So, in order to change my boot order to be Windows first, I would enter the command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0007,0001,0002,0003,0000,0008,0009,000A,0005,2001
```

This will set it in the EFI so that 'Windows Boot Manager' loads first, followed by 'ubuntu'. Every thing else stays where it was.

Note that some machines are hard coded to boot '[ESP]/BOOT/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi', (where [ESP] is your EFI system partition's filesystem) -- the Windows boot manager. However, simply copying '[ESP]/BOOT/ubuntu/bootx64.efi' to '[ESP]/Boot/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi' (after moving the original 'bootmgfw.efi' out of the way/backing it up of course) should suffice to fix the problem on those systems. If this is required, it can also be be done from within Ubuntu like this:

```
cp /boot/EFI/BOOT/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi /boot/EFI/BOOT/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi.bak
cp /boot/EFI/BOOT/ubuntu/bootx64.efi /boot/EFI/BOOT/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I followed what you said and ran the efibootmgr from the live cd and it did not list my ubuntu install. It shows the windows boot manager and my other hard drives, but that's it...

Comment: Did you do the Ubuntu install from legacy mode (purple screen at CD/USB boot) or from EFI (black screen at USB/CD boot)?

Answer (score 0):

**An Alternative Workaround**

1. While booting your laptop press the button which brings up `boot from device` menu.
2. Select your drive where you installed Ubuntu.
3. It should prompt you to choose either Windows or Ubuntu.
4. Select Ubuntu.
5. Now download [Ubuntu Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select recommended repair.
6. It will ask you to restart and should restart to GRUB menu.

Comment: This is on my desktop computer, but when I do bring up the boot menu, and I select the drive where I've installed ubuntu, nothing happens. It's just a blank screen and I'm forced to restart.

Comment: Boot from live Ubuntu Disc and do Boot repair as instructed above.